# What is a use-case? How to identify a use-case?

Tags: project-management, use-case

The question is quite generic. What are the points that should be kept in mind to identify a valid use case? How to approach a use case?

Comment: [**Use-case is everything**](http://www.slideshare.net/cvs26/usecase-is-everything) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A use case identifies, with specificity, a task or goal that users will be able to accomplish using a program. It should be written in terms that users can understand.

[Wikipedia's description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) is overly formal. I'll dig through my other texts shortly.
In contrast, [the original wiki's article](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?UseCase) is much more accessible.

An [early article](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Structuring+use+cases+with+goals) by Alastair Cockburn, cited positively by [*The Pragmatic Programmer*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X), contains a good template.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351665/use-cases-help), from just a few days ago, is very closely related, but slightly more specific.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of use case is simple:

> An actor's interactions with a system to create something of business value.

More formally:

> a sequence of transactions performed
>   by a system that yield a measurable
>   set of values for a particular actor.

They're intended to be very simple:  Actor, Interaction, Value.  You can add some details, but not too many.

Using use cases is easy.  Read this:  http://www.gatherspace.com/static/use_case_example.html

The biggest mistake is overlooking the interaction between actor and system.  A use case is not a place to write down long, detailed, technical algorithm designs.  A use case is where an actor *does* something.

People interact with systems so they can take actions (place orders, approve billing, reject an insurance claim, etc.)  To take an action, they first make a decision.  To make a decision, they need information

- Information
- Decision
- Action

These are the ingredients in the "Interaction" portion of a use case.

Comment: This was helpful to me. The "information" and "action" aspects of the interaction seem to perfectly align with the presentation and controls of a user interface respectively.

Answer (score 1):

A valid use case could describe:

- intended audience / user
- pre-requisites (ie must have logged in, etc)
- expected outcome(s)
- possible points of failure
- workflow of user

Answer (score 0):

From [Guideline: Identify and Outline Actors and Use Cases](http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openup/practice.tech.use_case_driven_dev.base/guidances/guidelines/identify_and_outline_actors_and_ucs_BB5516A9.html) by the Eclipse people:

> **Identifying actors**
>
> Find the external entities with which
>   the system under development must
>   interact. Candidates include groups of
>   users who will require help from the
>   system to perform their tasks and run
>   the system's primary or secondary
>   functions, as well as external
>   hardware, software, and other systems.
>
> Define each candidate actor by naming
>   it and writing a brief description.
>   Includes the actor's area of
>   responsibility and the goals that the
>   actor will attempt to accomplish when
>   using the system. Eliminate actor
>   candidates who do not have any goals.
>
> These questions are useful in
>   identifying actors:
>
> - Who will supply, use, or remove
>     information from the system?
> - Who will
>     use the system?
> - Who is interested in a
>     certain feature or service provided by
>     the system?
> - Who will support and
>     maintain the system?
> - What are the
>     system's external resources?
> - What
>     other systems will need to interact
>     with the system under development?
>
> Review the list of stakeholders that
>   you captured in the Vision statement.
>   Not all stakeholders will be actors
>   (meaning, they will not all interact
>   directly with the system under
>   development), but this list of
>   stakeholders is useful for identifying
>   candidates for actors.
>
> **Identifying use cases**
>
> The best way to find use cases is to
>   consider what each actor requires of
>   the system. For each actor, human or
>   not, ask:
>
> - What are the goals that the actor will
>     attempt to accomplish with the system?
> - What are the primary tasks that the
>     actor wants the system to perform?
> - Will the actor create, store, change,
>     remove, or read data in the system?
> - Will the actor need to inform the
>     system about sudden external changes?
> - Does the actor need to be informed
>     about certain occurrences, such as
>     unavailability of a network resource,
>     in the system?
> - Will the actor perform
>     a system startup or shutdown?
>
> Understanding how the target
>   organization works and how this
>   information system might be
>   incorporated into existing operations
>   gives an idea of system's
>   surroundings. That information can
>   reveal other use case candidates.
>
> Give a unique name and brief
>   description that clearly describes the
>   goals for each use case. If the
>   candidate use case does not have
>   goals, ask yourself why it exists, and
>   then either identify a goal or
>   eliminate the use case.
>
> **Outlining Use Cases**
>
> Without going into details, write a
>   first draft of the flow of events of
>   the use cases identified as being of
>   high priority. Initially, write a
>   simple step-by-step description of the
>   basic flow of the use case. The
>   step-by-step description is a simple
>   ordered list of interactions between
>   the actor and the system. For example,
>   the description of the basic flow of
>   the Withdraw Cash use case of an
>   automated teller machine (ATM) would
>   be something like this:
>
> 1. The customer inserts a bank card.
> 2. The system validates the card and prompts
>      the person to enter a personal
>      identification number (PIN).
> 3. The customer enters a PIN.
> 4. The system
>      validates the PIN and prompts the
>      customer to select an action.
> 5. The customer selects Withdraw Cash.
> 6. The system prompts the customer to choose
>      which account.
> 7. The customer selects
>      the checking account.
> 8. The system
>      prompts for an amount.
> 9. The customer
>      enters the amount to withdraw.
> 10. The
>       system validates the amount (assuming
>       sufficient funds), and then issues
>       cash and receipt.
> 11. The customer takes the cash and receipt, and then
>       retrieves the bank card.
> 12. The use case ends.
>
> As you create this step-by-step
>   description of the basic flow of
>   events, you can discover alternative
>   and exceptional flows. For example,
>   what happens if the customer enters an
>   invalid PIN? Record the name and a
>   brief description of each alternate
>   flow that you identified.
>
> **Representing relationships between
>   actors and use cases**
>
> The relationship between actors and
>   use cases can be captured, or
>   documented.  There are several ways to
>   do this. If you are using a use-case
>   model on the project, you can create
>   use-case diagrams to show how actors
>   and use cases relate to each other. 
>   Refer to Guideline: [Use-Case
>   Model](http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openup/practice.tech.use_case_driven_dev.base/guidances/guidelines/use_case_model_4C64E97D.html) for more information.
>
> If you are not using a use-case model
>   for the project, make sure that each
>   use case identifies the associated
>   primary and secondary actors.

Comment: Three words and a link, do not an answer make.  Your answer should be readable on its own, and include links for backup and elaboration.  It should not just say "look at this!".  What happens when that thing you linked to goes away?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I am stack noob. My bad. Will do my best from now on. :) And yeah, I've made the changes to my answer :)

Comment: I'd suggest trimming this down to just the relevant parts, and making it explicit that this was copied from somewhere.  At least there's info here now, though.